# Using Emacs on AWS Ubuntu system - Meta and Esc keys don't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, emacs

I am new to emacs and was trying to use it when I am editing files on an AWS server. The problem is that when I ssh from terminal (on my Mac) and try to use the Meta or Esc keys they don't work. The meta key just causes  characters like this --> √≈ß to appear. The esc key causes nothing to happen. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you running Emacs on the remote AWS instance, or locally on your Mac?

Comment: @Chris I am doing it on the remote AWS instance. Emacs works fine locally.

Comment: This is usually a translation problem with respect to key codes and can be difficult to track down as it could be your terminal emulator, the ssh implementation or the terminal emulator at the remote end. Most likely, it is one of the terminal emulation programs. My guess would be that the Esc key is not working because it is being consumed by your terminal emulator and not sent to the remote site. The meta/option key is probably not being straslated correctly before being sent. What you would need to do is use a utility which will dump out the key codes and mappings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very common to run Emacs locally (e.g. on your Mac) and edit files on remote systems using [TRAMP](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/), an excellent built-in library.

To edit a remote file over SSH, `find-file` using a pattern like

```
//ssh:user@host:path/to/file
```

In this case `path/to/file` is a path on the remote system relative to your home directory. As you might expect, starting this value with `/` lets you specify an absolute path.

I think that AWS forces you to specify a `.pem` key file for its SSH connections. The easiest way to make this work with Emacs is to add your AWS machine to `~/.ssh/config`, e.g.

```
Host example
HostName example.com
User ubuntu
IdentityFile ~/path/to/example.pem
```

and then edit `//ssh:example:path/to/file` in Emacs. Your SSH configuration settings should take effect.

It is also possible to use [multiple hops](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Multi_002dhops), which lets you chain together TRAMP methods, e.g. "SSH to server `example.com` and then edit file `some_file.txt` using `sudo`".